# Do I need to create a managed package in order for other instances to use my connected app?

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps

I've successfully created a managed package and put my connected app inside. Is that a step that's necessary for other instances to be able to call my connected app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to package the connected app for it to be available in any organization.